Difference between 95% Confidence Intervals in SPSS and R
When I calculate the 95% CI (Kaplan Meier curves) for a dataset in SPSS, it gives one set of values, and in R, another set of values.
I tried to compensate by adding conf.type = "log" or conf.type = "plain", etc...
Well, I tried each one, one after the other, but it still doesn't match the ones from SPSS.
Can anyone guide me? What am I doing wrong?

Welcome to the site! Are you trying to plot 95% CLs on a Kaplan Meier plot or obtain 95% CIs for mean or median survival time? I don't think SPSS automatically computes 95% CLs for the plots. This answer may help you understand more about those two R options.

It would help to include the code and the output, at least the CIs.

Because there are so many reasons such discrepancies can arise, including different processes for reading in the data, different numerical algorithms, different assumptions, different options, and so on, we really need you to give us some details.
